# Xml drawable not showing correctly in app

Tags: android, xml

I created an XML drawable like this 
[image: a part from the image]

and the xml is

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/cardview_light_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <size android:height="2dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"
                android:dashGap="48dp"
                android:dashWidth="@dimen/activity_default_margin" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top"
        android:left="32dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <size android:height="2dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#f9607d"
                android:dashGap="48dp"
                android:dashWidth="@dimen/activity_default_margin" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The image above is from the preview in the android studio. When the image is displayed in the emulator it shows a single line instead of the dashed lines. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: How do you use this drawable?

Comment: @PhátPhát as usual `android:background="@drawable/image"`

Comment: Try my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `ImageView` in your `xml` layout

```
android:layerType="software"
```